# Image Stacking showing is stacking all the bands in the whole image collection instead of images in the filtered image collection date

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth, image, stack

I have created my image collection of 36 images and I have mapped the NDVI function over it. I created a stacked image and assigned the kNDVI band to the image. However, it is showing 865 bands instead of 36 bands. What might be the reason for this?

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
                   .filterDate('2020-10-01','2021-04-30')
                   .filterBounds(Etosha)
                   .filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 5);
print('collection', collection);
print('Number of images in collection:', collection.size());

// Calculate KNDVI.
var addkNDVI = function(img) {
  // get a string representation of the date.
  var NIR = img.select('B8');
  var RED = img.select('B4');
 
  
  // Compute D2 a rename it to d2
  var D2 = NIR.subtract(RED).pow(2)
  .select([0],['d2']);
  
  // Gamma, defined as 1/sigmaˆ2
  var gamma = ee.Number(4e6).multiply(-2.0);
  
  // Compute kernel (k) and KNDVI
  var k = D2.divide(gamma).exp();
  var kndvi = ee.Image.constant(1)
  .subtract(k).divide(ee.Image.constant(1).add(k))
  .select([0],['kndvi']);
  return img.addBands(kndvi);
};
var kNDVIcollection = collection.map(addkNDVI);

var stackCollection = function(collection) {
  // Create an initial image.
  var first = ee.Image(collection.median()).select(['kndvi']);
    
  // Write a function that appends a band to an image.
  var appendBands = function(image, previous) {
    return ee.Image(previous).addBands(image);
  };
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(appendBands, first));
};
var stacked = stackCollection(kNDVIcollection);
print('stacked image', stacked);

// Display the Kndvi band in the stacked image.
Map.addLayer(stacked.select(0).clip(Etosha), {min:0, max:0.3}, 'stacked');
Map.centerObject(Etosha, 8);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but it looks like you are stacking each band in all images, and these images retain all their orignal bands plus the ndvi band you created. If you change "return img.addBands(kndvi)" to "return kndvi" do you get the desired output?

Comment: Yes, I did get the desired output. Thats the parameter that was needed. Thank you !